# Simple "SQL.Database(...)" leads to no support for DirectQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI I am confronted with the problem that a simple SQL.Database(...) "step results in  a query that is not supported in DirectQuery mode".

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?